# ExecutorService.awaitTermination runs into timeout despite active tasks

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following implementation:

```
final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
final List<Callable> taskList = new LinkedList<>();

for (Path path : paths) {
  final SomeCallable task = new SomeCallable(path);
  taskList.add(task);
  service.submit(task);
}
synchronized (this) {
  try {
    this.wait();
    shutdown(service);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    shutdown(service);
  }
}
```

And the following `shutdown(service)` method:

```
protected void shutdown(final ExecutorService service) {
  List<Runnable> abortedCallables = service.shutdownNow();
  try {
    if (!service.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
      System.out.println("timeout");
    }
  }
  catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // (Re-)cancel all Callables if current thread has been interrupted
    service.shutdownNow();
    // Preserve interrupt status
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }
}
```

My problem is the following: `paths` is a list of a lot of `Path` instances. All of these paths will undergo some processing within a `SomeCallable` instance. Usually, `this` thread waits until all paths have been successfully handled within their `SomeCallable`. Once all paths have been processed `shutdown(service)` will be called.

However, it may happen that `this` thread is interrupted and has to be shutdown immediately. Therefore, I call `shutdown(service)` within the `catch`-block. What is working is, that currently running `SomeCallable`-instances will be finished and none of the tasks within the ExecutorService's thread pool will be started. Nonetheless, `awaitTermination` always runs into the 2 minute timeout. Why is this?

I assumed that `awaitTermination` waits for currently active running tasks to terminate (hence, wait for a maximum of 4 tasks -> thread pool size). Two minutes - in my case - is more than enough time for the 4 tasks to finish. As by calling `shutdownNow()` no new tasks from the queue should be started I wonder why I still get the timeout.

Any ideas?

Comment: " Two minutes - in my case - is more than enough time for the 4 tasks to finish." - do you mean finish normally, or stop doing what they're doing when interrupted and finish ?

Comment: I mean finishing normally - within the Callables there is no loop that would run forever.

Comment: I fear the problem is beyond what information you've supplied so far.

Comment: What information do you think is missing? Assuming that I have 100 paths, all paths will be submitted to the service. Then `this.wait()` is called. If now, after 20 processed tasks an interrupt occurs the method `shutdown()` is called. The list `abortedCallables` subsequently contains 80 items. I.e. I have got 20 processed tasks and 80 which have not been started. Hence, from my point of view, there should be no timeout at all.

Comment: Well, obviously the SomeCallable instances aren't finishing, but without knowing what they're doing (what code they are running), it's impossible to tell why.

Comment: You were right, an analysis showed that the threads were still running. Changed the design a little bit, and now they are being terminated properly